# The Twitter name is mispelled

Tags: bug, status-completed

The [@StackDIY](https://twitter.com/#!/StackDIY) account seems to have a bit of a uh, tyop in the name:

[image]

Instead of "DIY Stack Excahnge", it should be "DIY Stack Exchange".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the report, it should be all better now.

Comment: Thank you! All good now.